# How to remove 2 last segment in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to remove and replace a specific parts of url.

Suppose my url is :

http://www.example.com/45/10/2016

I want to replace only the last 2 segments 10/2016, 
I know how to replace the last segment using :

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var new_url  = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

But i can't figure out how to control and manipulate a specific segments in a string, perhaps there is a way in JS to divide a string into segment and then say "ok- do this to segment #3"....
Thanks.

Comment: billions of question about this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a a part of a text string in a span class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740994/how-to-remove-a-a-part-of-a-text-string-in-a-span-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var url ='http://www.example.com/45/10/2016'
 var parts  = url.split('/')
 // change segments  
 parts[4] = '12';
 parts[5] = '2017';

 var new_url = parts.join('/')
```